# Python pandas : pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default' causes graph crash

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Everything is in the title. My graph is displayed properly when I do not set this option at the beginning of my python script, otherwise it opens the window for the graph but closes it straightback and end the run.

I am using pandas 0.14.0 and matplotlib 1.3.0.

Anyone already saw this ? You can see my code below if needed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000',periods=1000), columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df.cumsum()
df.plot(legend=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you try with %matplotlib inline on an ipython notebook? That worked for me, which suggests an issue with your backend

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and yes it seems to be a backend issue. my error comes from: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py(166)get_text_width_height_descent()`

Comment: @cd98: could you elaborate? not sure what syntax you're suggesting exactly.

Comment: @grisaitis, the `%matplotlib` is an IPython notebook magic to change the backend of `matplotlib`. The `inline` part is to use a backend so that graphs are displayed, well, inline in the notebook. The default backend varies between OS and will open up a new window to display the graph.

Answer (score 12):

I was experiencing a similar error with Matplotlib v1.4.  The solution I found is to use

```
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
```

rather than

```
pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'
```

See - https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/visualization.html

Answer (score 9):

Use the following:

`plt.show(block=True)`

Comment: Works for me with pandas 0.14.1 on OS X 10.9.4.